# chrome sidepanel send message content_scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**sidepanel-JS**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
      id: 'writeUrl',
      glataUrl: glataUrl.value
    },
    response => {
      console.log(response)
    }
  )
```

**content_scripts -JS**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(sender)
  console.log('Message received in content_scripts:', message)
  // 处理消息
  if ((message.id = 'writeUrl')) {
    writeItamGlataUrl(message.glataUrl)
  }
  // 可选地，您可以回复消息
  sendResponse({ response: 'Message received!' })
})
```

When I sent a message on sidepanel's js, the error was shown in the picture, and it seemed that I couldn't find the receiver.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDUQL.png)

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime?hl=zh-cn
I have referred to the official documents, but I haven't solved it.

Answer (score 0):

chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
tabId: number,
message: any,
options?: object,
callback?: function,
)

I found a solution because chrome.runtime.sendMessage cannot send messages to content scripts and can only use chrome.tabs.sendMessage